# Trying to use FOR loop inside of the string. (Js, jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code:

```
$.each(data, function(i,v){
  $('#user-grid').append(
    '<a href="my_urls">' +
      '<div>' + v.points + '</div>' +
      '<div>' + v.other + '</div>' +
    '</a>'
  );
});
```

Into the user grid div, I append the string with the values taken from data.

v.points and v.other are the numbers.

To this moment, everything works just fine. But what I need is to embed the for loop into the divs. In the places where I have v.points and v.other I want to put two simular FOR loops.

```
for(var i = 0; i < v.points; i++) {
  //here is the html line that should be passed to the div, where v.points are now
  <div>This is the point</div>
}
```

And almost the same for the v.other. Only with another line that should be pasted.

So basically how can I do that? I was trying to paste this loops right inside the "append()" but that didn't work out. I was also trying to create a variable inside of the loop and pass it in to the append, but got only one result, instead of all that I have needed.

Comment: Loop inside `append` won't work (unless it's a functional loop like `map`). Constructing a variable in a loop then passing it to `append` should be correct; please show the code you tried to run. Also, very importantly, please make a mock-up of the output you are trying to get (for instance, I don't know if you want `points` and `other` to go sequentially or interleaved).

Comment: your for loop example is not syntactically valid

Comment: please let me know your `data` structure!

Comment: More information would be helpful!!

Comment: is v.points an array?

Comment: I want few main links to be outputted. This is handled by $.each. In each link, I want first few of the points to be outputted and then few of the 'other' elements. To output the points and the other I need a for loop. I have a desired number - how much times do I want each one of them to be outputted . This number is v.points and v.other. It is taken from the data.

Comment: v.points and v.other are the numbers. (Already told that). there is no use in telling the data structure. v.points and v.other should be considered as variables.

Comment: About the validation of the loop structure - that is what I am basically trying to understand. How should I use it within this situation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what are you looking for, this code prints 5 "This is your point" and 3 "This is your other" inside the anchor.

```
var data = [
    {
        points: 5,
        other: 3
    }
]

function printPoints(vPoints){
    var str = "";
    for(var i=0; i<vPoints; i++) {
        str+="<div>"+"This is your point"+"</div>";
    }
    return str;
}

function printOther(vOther){
    var str = "";
    for(var i=0; i<vOther; i++) {
        str+="<div>"+"This is your other"+"</div>";
    }
    return str;
}

$.each(data, function(i,v){
  $('#user-grid').append(
    '<a href="my_urls">' +
      printPoints(v.points)+
      printOther(v.other)+
    '</a>'
  );
});
```

See it on action [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vaejmzvg/)

Comment: Wow, thats great! Thanks a lot.